# Linking External Data in Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

I have a Cognito Form which contains a name and I would like to be able to validate that name against an approved list. I do not want to use a drop-down otherwise other users will be able to see all the names and possibly select the incorrect one by accident.

Also, I am using the Save & Resume feature and I would like to pre-populate the email address for the resume message based on the name entered on the form.

I have a table which contains the items I need so my question is how can I read data from a data table and use it to validate/pre-populate Cognito fields ?

Comment: Hi Ian! Please check your email to see our response to your support request.